# How to access property of constructed object in an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, properties, constructor

For instance if I construct a new object type and create a few objects

```
    function website(name,users)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.users = users;
    }

    var goog = new website("goog", "3,000,000");
    var fireFox = new website("fireFox", "1,000,000");
    var ie = new website("ie", "10");
```

And I push them into an array

```
    var websites = [];
    websites.push(goog,fireFox,ie);
```

Is there a way I can access a property of each object in the array through a loop?
For instance

```
    for (var i=0;var<websites.length;i++)
        {
             console.log(websites[0.name]);
        }
```

I know this code doesn't work but I hope it clarifies what I'm trying to ask.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you say

```
websites[0.name]
```

It will try to get `0`'s `name` property, which is not valid. So, you should access it like this

```
websites[i].name
```

`websites[i]` will refer to the WebSite object in the array, at the index `i` and you are getting the name property with the `.` operator.

Also, your loop variable should be used in the `for` loop's condition, like this

```
for (var i=0; i < websites.length; i++)
```

Comment: Ah I see and I got my code to work. Thank you for your thorough explanation!